# All of a sudden my index.cshtml page shows does not load the css and javascript and other files

Tags: javascript, html, css, razor, bootstrap-4

[See the image here, in the network tab its saying not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvCoL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvCoL.png)

Any solution for this ?

Can't figure out anything

Comment: Update, when the page is first loaded, it takes the css and javascript and other files from the correct folder (that is css/style.css and js/script.js) but when the page is loaded with typing the URL the path is different (that is url/homecontroller/cs/style)

Comment: Hi @Code Noob, could you pls share the code and where do you add the css and js files?

Comment: Hi @Rena 
data-setbg='/img/PlanceDark.png'